# Custom analyzer in Elasticsearch index template

Tags: elasticsearch

Can I create an Elasticsearch index template and specify a custom analyzer?

I see I can do this when creating an index itself but I need to do it in a mapping.

Comment: Maybe this post help you: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/unable-to-create-template-with-analyzer/124708/3?u=rabbit_br